# Put in the TXT file value with Enter

Tags: php

Im triyng to put some values in my txt file:

```
foreach($result as $res)
{
    file_put_contents("nicknames.txt", $res);
}
```

It works, but values puts in one-line without Enter(\r\n).
But when i try to add Enter:

```
foreach($result as $res)
{
    file_put_contents("nicknames.txt", $res."\r\n");
}
```

i receive "Array" in my txt doc. Why?

Thank you, i find my error, there is array in array) I forget abou it, sorry)

Comment: What's the content of `$res`?

Comment: If `$res` is array, then concatenating it with another string makes it a string too.

Comment: You could append all `$res` ex: `@$foo .= $res.'<br/>'` and just write `$foo` after existing the loop. Not the best way, but it's finger licking quick

Comment: you could prepare content first and then write it in one go instead of writing to file within a loop. And you want to append the content not overwrite it.

Comment: @Qǝuoɯᴉs: `<br>` in a text file? That it not going to be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The first issue i see with this code is that you are putting new content on each loop... What you want is to add the `FILE_APPEND` flag to it to append data at the end of the file instead of overwritting it.

I can't understand though why you are getting array written in the second example, it makes no sense...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are repeatedly overwriting the existing contents, so the result will be just one item.

Try this:

```
file_put_contents("nicknames.txt",implode("\n",$result));
```

Comment: This is one problem for sure, but it does not sufficiently explain where `Array` comes from. We'd need to know what we are imploding here to make sure that this will work.

Comment: What I don't get is why "just adding `\r\n`" supposedly causes it to show Array instead. @GuitarFan, we need a `var_dump`!